# Is there a way to view/peek into the uri that Invoke-RestMethod is constructing?

Tags: python, powershell, rest

I don't know much about restAPIs, I am using PowerShell to learn more about them.

Currently I want see the final URI address that is constructed by clients such as `Invoke-RestMethod` and python's `requests` library.

Looking at the documentation examples for `Invoke-RestMethod`, [Example 4: Simplified Multipart/Form-Data Submission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.3#example-4-simplified-multipart-form-data-submission), constructs a URI (I think) using the `$Form` hashtable and then `Invokest-RestMethod` is invoked with it.

Is there a way to intercept this message? If not, then, is there by any chance a public restAPI out there that lets you see the call you made to it, as it is received it?

For example, [Placeholder](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/), is useful tool I recently came across, its for "Free fake API for testing and prototyping." It would be nice to have something similar for seeing the URI address that is being sent to a website.

The API documentation for Regex101, has a few nice example like this one [Python](https://github.com/firasdib/Regex101/wiki/API#python-3) but none of them are in PowerShell, I am trying convert the Python ones to PowerShell but its hard without seeing what the final result is.

I am working in the dark here and I feel that I need to actually see what I am doing.

```
$Uri = 'https://api.contoso.com/v2/profile'
$Form = @{
    firstName  = 'John'
    lastName   = 'Doe'
    email      = 'john.doe@contoso.com'
    avatar     = Get-Item -Path 'c:\Pictures\jdoe.png'
    birthday   = '1980-10-15'
    hobbies    = 'Hiking','Fishing','Jogging'
}
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Form $Form
```

With the above example, what is the URI string `Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Form $Form` is going transmit to `api.contoso.com`?

PS: I am not designing a restAPI, merely learning how to call them.

Comment: What is your question about? I'm lost

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, I edited my question, added some code examples now. I hope that is better.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for something like Burp Suit or related to intercept the request. In any case, I dont see how this is a programming question, seems much more relevant for a site like super user or other

Comment: Maybe you're after a debugging endpoint like `httpbin.org`?  It's a web service that's  will echo back the request they received: `$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://httpbin.org/get" -Method Get; $response | ConvertTo-Json`

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. You're already specifying the URI. Do you actually mean you want to see the HTTP request body that's being sent? You could use a tool like Wireshark to do that.

Comment: If you add `-Verbose` it'll show you exactly which URI(s) it's hitting

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen it was that easy...the things you now. Cheers!

Comment: @ndc85430 perhaps I am getting my terminology mixed, I will look into this Wireshark to see if it has what I am looking for, thanks.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala this sounds like exactly what I am after, "Maybe you're after a debugging endpoint like httpbin.org? It's a web service that's will echo back the request they received". I will spend the day looking into this. Cheers!